# Getting information about "What are you doing" activity from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get information from using facebook api about a status update like
"Narendra Rajput is watching American Hustle".
This was created by using "Say what are you doing" feature.
I tried getting information about it using graph api and FQL using stream table. It does give me postid and permalink and all other fields are empty or null.
I tried using graph api too but again all fields are empty except postid and permalink.
In FQL I tried this query to get the information about posts

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, attribution, attachment, app_data, action_links,  impressions, description_tags ,description,tagged_ids, message,message_tags, attachment, type, permalink
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me()
AND is_hidden != "true"
AND (type = 46 OR type = 60 OR type = 65 OR type = 80 OR type = 128 OR type = 247 OR type = 285 OR type = 373)
LIMIT 100
```

I tried all possible fields in stream table.
I want the text "Narendra Rajput is watching American Hustle" from this status update as it appears in the news feed.
How can I get this information. Is it possible with FB api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this information is not available via the `FQL`, it's only available via the `Graph API`.

You will need the `user_actions.video` and `friends_actions.video` permissions for accessing it.

Once you have the access to these endpoints you, can fetch it via-

https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches?access_token= # valid access token

Replace the `me` with your friends `Facebook ID` to fetch data for his/her `video.watches`.